# About inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I am confused about

> super.i = j+1;

this line of code. I think it only change the variable i in class A, and dosen't change the inherited variable i in class B.

To make the question clear, I add another sample(sample 2). In sample 2, we use

> super(balance,name);

to initialize the attributes inherited from the parent class. When we call super and change the variable balance and name, we don't change the variable balance and name in parent class.

In sample 1, we use

> super.i = j+1;

We actually change the variable i in parent class, not the variable i inherited from the parent class. What's the difference between these two samples? Thank you so much.

---

**edited July 18,2019**

I have added a diriver class in sample 2. After we create an object c in CheckingAccount, the balance in c is 200 and name is "XYZ". We use super(argument) in subclass, do we change the balance and name in superclass?
If not, why the variable i in Sample 1 is changed?

```
//Sample one
class A{
    int i;
}

class B extends A{
    int j;
    void display() {
        super.i = j+1;
        System.out.println(j+ " "+i);
    }
}

public class CC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        B obj = new B();
        obj.i =1;
        obj.j = 2;
        obj.display();
    }

}
```

```
//sample 2
//parent class
public class BankAccount {

    protected double balance=0;
    protected String name="ABC";

    public BankAccount(double balance, String name) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

//child class

public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount{
    final int CHARGE = 5;
    final int NO_CHARGE = 0;
    private boolean hasInterest;

    public CheckingAccount(double balance, String name, boolean hasInterest) {
        super(balance,name);
        this.hasInterest = hasInterest;
    }
}

//driver class
public class DriveClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckingAccount c = new CheckingAccount(200,"XYZ",true);
}
}
```

The output is

> 2 3

Comment: In your code, `super.i = j+1;` is equivalent to `this.i = j+1;`

Comment: why? super and this key word are totally different, right?

Comment: In this case they are referencing the same variable.  In fact, you don't need `this` or  `super` to change `i`.  And you **are** changing the inherited variable.

Comment: In your new example, both `balance` and `name` are inherited.  They are being set with the constructor in A via the `super` qualifier  in B's constructor.  As long as you are in the constructor, the `balance and name parameters` are local to the constructor and are different than the inherited fields of the same name.  But once the constructor is exited, those values go out of scope and are no longer relevant.  From that point on, the inherited versions will be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is where `i` in class B hides `i` in class A.  And `this.i` and `super.i` are different.

```java
class A {
   int i;

   void print() {
      System.out.println("i = " + i);
   }
}

class B extends A {
   int j;
   int i;

   void display() {
      i = j + 1;
      super.i = 1000;
      System.out.println(j + " " + i);
      print(); // this will print the i in A
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question and make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you again. You said "But once the constructor is exited, those values go out of scope and are no longer relevant. From that point on, the inherited versions will be used." Does it mean that the value of inherited fields are changed? What about the fields in parent class with the same name? I have added a driver class in question. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Those values in the parent class will be changed.  If the child class has instance fields of the same name as the parent class, then those will `hide` the parent (inherited) class values.  I demonstrated that in my example above with B extending A.  In that example, `i` in the child class hides `i` in the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

> super(balance, name)

This called the constructor of the parent class to initialize the variable balance and name in the parent class. Yes, it did change the value of balance and name in parent class

> super.i = j+1

This assigned j+1 to the parent class variable i.

One is initialize the parent class variable through constructor and the other one is assigning value directly to parent class variable. Both are different